# Flink: does Flink support abstract operator which can process different data streams with common fields?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Suppose we have multiple data streams and they share some common features.

For example, we have a stream of **Teacher** and a stream of **Student**, and they both have an **age** field. If I want to find out the eldest student or teacher from the realtime stream, I can implement an operator as below.

```
public MaxiumAgeFunc extends RichMapFunction<Student,Integer> {
    int maxAge;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Student s, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        if(s.age > maxAge){
            maxAge = s.age;
        }
        collector.collect(maxAge);
    }
}
```

To find out the eldest **Teacher**, we need to implement a similar operator as below

```
public MaxiumAgeFunc extends RichMapFunction<Teacher,Integer> {
    int maxAge;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Teacher t, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        if(t.age > maxAge){
            maxAge = t.age;
        }
        collector.collect(maxAge);
    }
}
```

But actually these two operators have common process logic, so my idea is to define a parent class, such as **People**.

```
public class People{
    public Integer age;
}
```

Then **Student** and **Teacher** can be defined as their child class, and also keep their own fields.

```
public class Student extends People {
    public Integer grade;  // student grade
    ...
}
```

```
public class Student extends People {
    public Integer subject;  // the subject that teacher teaches
    ...
}
```

In this case, I can define an operator as below.

```
public MaxiumAgeFunc extends RichMapFunction<People,Integer> {
    int maxAge;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(People p, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        if(t.age > maxAge){
            maxAge = p.age;
        }
        collector.collect(maxAge);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this operator to implement a Flink execution topology, it won't work because of the unmatched data type.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<Student> studentStream = env.addSource(...);
DataStream<Teacher> teacherStream = env.addSource(...);

studentStream.map(new MaxiumAgeFunc()).print();
teacherStream.map(new MaxiumAgeFunc()).print();
```

And this is my question, is it possible to make an abstract operator for input streams having common fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a Java than a Flink question:

What you want to do is to make `MaxiumAgeFunc` parameterized like this

```
public MaxiumAgeFunc<T extends People> extends RichMapFunction<T, Integer> {
    int maxAge;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(T p, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        if(t.age > maxAge){
            maxAge = p.age;
        }
        collector.collect(maxAge);
    }
}
```

and then use it like this

```
studentStream.map(new MaxiumAgeFunc<>()).print();
teacherStream.map(new MaxiumAgeFunc<>()).print();
```

edit:

btw your function is not working with [checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html) (so will produce wrong results upon recovery from a checkpoint) and I'd rather go with an aggregation function over the [global window](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#global-windows).

```
students
    .windowAll(GlobalWindows.create())
    .aggregate(new AggregateFunction<People, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer createAccumulator() {
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer add(People value, Integer accumulator) {
            return Math.max(value.age, accumulator);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getResult(Integer accumulator) {
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer merge(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return Math.max(a, b);
        }
    });
```

Comment: yep, I know that, thanks for your reminding, I was just trying to simplify the question:)